# Does linking a new framework in a project have any negative impacts on app performance?

Tags: ios, performance, frameworks, import

For example, when I code like this: `anView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;` ,I need to link `QuartzCore.framework` in my project and import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in header file.

I am wondering if this will have any negative impacts on app performance while linking new framework.

I am not sure this so I always try to subclass an UIView like this.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds cornerRadius: 5];
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.2 alpha: 0.75] set];
    [path fill];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will definitely optimize the code. If you linked a framework without importing it, it will neglect the linked framework. In your case, there may be a slight impact on performance since you used a property `cornerRadius` in that framework, but it is so subtle that you cannot possibly feel the difference.